# Web API works with Windows authentication enabled when consumed via Swagger but throws an unauthorized issue when accessed through web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication, restful-authentication

Im trying to consume asp.net web api(Rest) through my webapp. It throws unauthorized error.
Only windows authentication is enabled in Webapi.

Note :- Both api and web app is built on .net48.

[WebAPI Authentication Settings in server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgPyM.png)

When I invoke APi I have set the UseDefaultCredentials to true in HttpclientHandler.

[UseDefaultCredentials set to true in HttpclientHandler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fUwC.png)

This works in my local machine. But in server it throws error.

Can anyone please help me here?

If I enable anonymous authentication in Webapi it works.

But, It should only work on windows authentication. I have set authentication mode to windows in web.config.

[web.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOMDA.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)